# Is it possible to call a controller using Jquery Ajax and load the model in View (not in partial view)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a code now that call the controller using ajax and it is working fine. My problem now when I about to load the model in the view. I had a jquery error. Note also I reuse the view to load the model

Ajax code

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDetails", "Employee")',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        //how to load the data in the index view?
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Connection Failed. Please Try Again.");
                    }
                });
```

In the Employee Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetEmployeeDetails()
{

    var model = new EmployeeDetails();//  I got the logic inside of this

   //reused the existing view
   return View("Index", model);
}
```

I debug it, and I confirmed that I can pass until in the returning of the model to View then I will have error in the AJAX

Comment: why u return view?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Actually I don't have an idea on how to do it. but what I'm trying to achieve is to load the model in the same view of the Index method - so I wil not create a new view instead I will reuse it if possible

Comment: This makes no sense at all. Your jquery is asking the server for JSON, but you return some HTML to it. And you can't return a whole view to ajax, because that's an entire HTML document, but you already have one of those - you might want to use a Partial View instead, which would return a snippet of HTML you could insert into your existing document. Or maybe you want to return just some data (e.g. just the actual model data itself, as JSON), it's not very clear from your wording.

Comment: Either way, you can't "do nothing" in the success of the ajax, as you mentioned - at least not if you want anything to change on your page. You have to actually make some use of what the server sends back to you from the ajax call, otherwise you will not have achieved anything useful. I wonder if you do not really understand AJAX properly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, what im trying to do is I want to load data that i have from getemployeedetails to Index view

Comment: you want to load it _into_ the Index view? Then why are you returning the view itself? I think you _probably_ want to return the data as JSON, and then write some Javascript to load that data into the view (which, don't forget, is already loaded in the user's browser). Or maybe you want to return some ready-made HTML containing the employee data (via a Partial View) which you can then insert into the existing view (again via Javascript). Choose one of those options and go for it.